# How to get Internet Explorer advanced tab information c#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

How to get Advanced Tab information in Internet option.

[image]

In system, where this data is getting save.?

Comment: This question is best suited for Superuser. See here for an existing answer on Superuser: https://superuser.com/a/598663/302689

Comment: @sorifiend, Its not giving information of check or uncheck. It gives  default value.

Comment: I don't know have an answer then, that was just the first result I found from a quick search on superuser. Try your own search and see what you can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Please find below link:

https://getadmx.com/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::Advanced_DisableClearType

This link contains all path to get the registry value of Advance IE Setting.

Hopefully, it will be useful for other.